# Cell voltage with different n factors

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry, redox

I’m a bit confused regarding cell potentials. If I have two half  reactions each involving a different number of electrons, there are two ways I can see to calculate the net emf of their cell:

1. Simply add the potentials across the two theoretical half cells, that is, treat each half reaction as a voltage source in series
2. Calculate the value for the net cell reaction as a whole, that is, make consideration for the energetics of the reaction

As a more specific example, say I have a metal $\text M$, and $$\ce{E^0_{M^{3+}/M}=2V, E^0_{M^{2+}/M}=1V}$$ and would like to figure the standard cell potential, say $x$ of $\ce{E^0_{M^{3+}/M^{2+}}}$.

With **Method 1** we have $$x= \ce{{E^0_{M^{3+}/M}}-{E^0_{M^{2+}/M}}}=2-1=\mathbf{1V}$$

With **Method 2** we have $$\ce{\Delta G^0_{M^{3+}/M}=-3*F*2=-6F, \Delta G^0_{M^{2+}/M}=-2*F*1=-2F}$$
$$\implies \ce{\Delta G^0_{net} = -6F - (-2F) = -4F}$$
$$\implies x=\frac{-\ce{4F}}{\ce{-1*F}}=\mathbf{4V}$$

How do I rectify these inconsistent values? Does it make any difference here whether I say I am looking for $\ce{E^0_{M^{3+}/M^{2+}}}$ or $\ce{M|M^{2+}(1 molar)||M^{3+}(1 molar)|M}$? What if I use an inert electrode like $\ce{Pt}$ in the latter representation?

Further, if I have another metal $\ce Y$ for which $\ce{E^0_{Y^+/Y}}=\ce{3V}$, which is a stronger oxidizing agent? $\ce{M^{3+}}$ or $\ce Y^+$?

In various sources it seems some use method 1 while others use 2. In [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/22141/84472) answer on CSE it seems 1 is the right one. But I maybe missing some conceptual context.

Thanks!

Comment: Cell potential is not additive but free energy is.. and so the second method is accurate/correct.. Try using method 2 in that reaction and it would be correct as well.

Comment: Conceptually related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/136774/95133

Comment: The first method is actually derived from the second one. In case of "different-elements" Galvanic cell, the first method works, but in case of disproportionation, it doesn't.

Comment: @RahulVerma Whats the difference in such a cell? It is the same physical process, so why should there be different rules? And does this have any thing to do with the electrodes—I.e. if I use an inert electrode will it behave like a normal galvanic cell ?

And I did figure where the first method comes from, it’s rather the order of operations, if you will, that I find confusing. 

@ Safdar But won’t that also give a mathematically different result since in one case it is a simple difference and the other is a weighted average of sorts ?

Comment: Take any example of "different elements" cell (say Cu-Ag Galvanic cell), and then use the second method to calculate E(cell). You'll always end up with same values from both methods.

Comment: Simply speaking, the first method is wrong. You can't use it.. It just so happens that it works for redox reactions, but it is not general..

Comment: @Safdar, I'd say that the first method isn't wrong, it's just specific to "different elements" cell. No?

Comment: @RahulVerma It is a **specific case**, it just happens to work.. You can't use it as a general method and so I would say it is wrong (from a purely conceptual frame).

Comment: @RahulVerma Is that really true? By method 2 you get a completely different mathematical expression, in this example ${E^0_{\text{cell}}={(-F\cdot0.8)-(-2F\cdot0.34)\over -2F}=0.06V}$ unless I’ve got Method 2 wrong, but if I have then it works for disproportionation also $\dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question properly, you are asking - in the condition $E^\circ_{\ce{M^3+/M^2+}} =\pu{4 V}$, $E^\circ_{\ce{M^3+/M}} =\pu{1 V}$, $E^\circ_{\ce{Y+/Y}} =\pu{3 V}$ - whether $\ce{M^3+}$ is a stronger oxidising agent than $\ce{Y+}$ irrespective of it going to $\ce{M \text{or} M^2+}$.

This would not be true since $\ce{Y+}$ has a higher reducing potential than $\ce{M^3+/M}$ but not $\ce{M^3+/M^2+}$, and so $\ce{M^3+}$ would be a stronger oxidising agent than $\ce{Y+}$ where it converts into $\ce{M^2+}$ **but not when $\ce{M^3+}$ converts into $\ce{M}$**.

---

The method $1$ that you suggest is a very specific case that can only be used for a general redox reaction. By this, I mean a reaction as follows for a cell having it cell notation denoted as $[\ce{N(s)|N^{y+}(aq)|| M^{x+}(aq)|M(s)}]$

\begin{array} {rlllc} \require{cancel}
\ce{N^y+ + ye- &-> N } &E^\circ = E_n^\circ &\quad|\times(-x)\\
\ce{ M^x+ +xe- &-> M}  &E^\circ = E_m^\circ &\quad|\times(y)  \\  \hline
\ce{yM^x+ + xN  +\cancel{(xye-)}  &-> yM + xN^y+ + \cancel{(xye-)}} &E^\circ = E_{\text{cell}}^\circ  \\ 
\end{array}

So here, if you apply method $1$, you get $E^\circ_\text{cell} = E^\circ_m -E^\circ_n$

Let's see whether this works using method $2$ (the free energy varient). Now, we know that $\Delta G$ is additive, $\Delta G^\circ =nFE^\circ$ and that when we multiply the total reaction by a value, we also multiply the $\Delta G$ by the same number. Using these properties we find the $\Delta G$ values for the two reactions.

For just one mole of M being reduced , we get

$$\Delta G_{\text{m}}=xFE^\circ_m \tag{1}$$

For just one mole of N, we get

$$\Delta G_{\text{n}}=yFE^\circ_n \tag{2}$$

Now, according to the above cell reaction, the $\Delta G_{\mathrm {cell}} = y(\Delta G_m) + (-x)\Delta G_n$ which would be equal to

\begin{align}
\Delta G_{\text{cell}} &= (-x)yFE^\circ_n + (y)xFE^\circ_m \\
&= xyF(E^\circ_m -E^\circ_n) \tag{3}
\end{align}

Now, the value of $\Delta G_{\text{cell}}$ in terms of $E^\circ_\text{cell}$, we get:

$$\Delta G_{\text{cell}}=xyFE^\circ_\text{cell} \tag{4}$$

Now substituting this value of $\Delta G_\text{cell}$ into equation (3), we get

\begin{align}
\cancel{(xyF)}E^\circ_\text{cell} &= \cancel{(xyF)}(E^\circ_m -E^\circ_n) \\
\implies E^\circ_\text{cell} &= E^\circ_m -E^\circ_n
\end{align}

For a case where you have the same compound disproportionate, [this question and its answers](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/136774/95133) should be enough.